# Collapsing shell of null matter

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon

In Naked Singularity (1973), Penrose claimed that the inequality
$$A\leq 16\pi G m_0$$
is equivalent to
$$4\pi\int r^2 \Omega \leq [\int r(1-\nabla^2\ln r)\Omega]^2$$
in the spherical symmetric case (LHS is trivial). He gave a detailed argument which I however failed to formulate in expressions to get the above inequality:

> "The divergence of N at S measures the intensity of the energy
> of the shell at $S_0$ (since this intensity is exactly sufficient to reduce the divergence to zero). Scaling this intensity down by the inverse square of the appropriate luminosity parameter on H, we obtain the initial intensity of the shell at infinity. Integrating this over the sphere at infinity, we obtain $m_0$."

In "Collapsing Shells and the Isoperimetric Inequality for Black Holes", Gibbons put a seemingly simpler account for Penrose Inequality (the first inequality above)

> "one needs to know the ratio of the $\frac{1}{n-1}$ root of the area $A(T)$ to $\frac{1}{n-2}$ root of the the integral
> $$\int_T l^\alpha_{;\alpha} \, dA$$"

All these arguments are intuitively obvious but I fail to formulate inequalities as they put it. I think my confusion started already when they invoke Raychaudhuri equation to link expansion/divergence to mass energy density. For example, one form of Raychaudhuri equation is (Wikipedia)
$$\partial_u \theta +\frac{1}{n-2}\theta^2 =-2\sigma^2 -8\pi G T_{uu}$$

**Given that a discontinuity in $\theta$ is expected, how does one relate $T_{uu}$ to $\theta$ on a codim-2 surface, specifically $\theta$ at $S_0$ would drop to zero after crossing the null shell?**

It got be some jump condition, right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I read that this paper gives a detailed account for the junction condition: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0201054.pdf

Comment: The first inequality of Penrose is shown in details in Tod's 'Penrose’s quasi-local mass and the isoperimetric inequality for static black holes' as equation (9).